# FacebookLogin from react-facebook-login is getting automatically called when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props'

class MyLogin extends React.Component {
  responseFacebook(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <FacebookLogin
        appId="1088597931155576"
        autoLoad
        callback={this.responseFacebook}
        render={renderProps => (
       <button onClick={renderProps.onClick}>This is my custom FB button</button>
      )}
     />
    );
  }
}
```

Now, as soon as my page gets loaded, the responseFacebook function is executed. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given answer did not work for me. This is an alternative approach, using `react-facebook` now.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { FacebookProvider, Login } from 'react-facebook';
 
export default class Example extends Component {
  handleResponse = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
 
  handleError = (error) => {
    this.setState({ error });
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookProvider appId="123456789">
        <Login
          scope="email"
          onCompleted={this.handleResponse}
          onError={this.handleError}
        >
          {({ loading, handleClick, error, data }) => (
            <span onClick={handleClick}>
              Login via Facebook
              {loading && (
                <span>Loading...</span>
              )}
            </span>
          )}
        </Login>
      </FacebookProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove "autoLoad" line. You won't get that behavior once removed.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, I uninstalled the react-instagram-login because I don't know why it causes problems in the react-facebook-login and it worked again.
Pretty weird.